# Jupyter Lab interactive image display : issue with widgets arrangements using HBox

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am trying to change content of an image interactively using a slider (e.g. for applying a threshold operation with different values).

My code is as follows:

```
#%matplotlib ipympl
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2
import numpy as np

import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, IntSlider
from IPython.display import Image

def update_lines(change):
    ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_gray,change.new,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    plt.imshow(thresh2)
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

image = cv2.imread("Untitled.jpg")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_gray,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

slider = IntSlider(
    orientation='vertical',
    step=1,
    value=127,
    min=0,
    max=255
)

display(HBox([slider, fig.canvas]))

slider.observe(update_lines, names='value')
```

When executing my code, I have an unexpected behavior: the figure is displayed twice, the first time when I do `fig = plt.figure()` and the second time when I do `display(HBox([slider, fig.canvas]))` => see [The figure is displayed twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWX4J.jpg).

How can I display the image only into the HBox ?

When I change the value with the slider, I have the following result => [After changing value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pa7p.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that matplotlib cannot directly be persuaded to plot the figure at the `figure()` call, but it's possible to encapsulate it in an `Output` widget (taken from [here](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/)):

```
output = widgets.Output()
with output:
  fig = plt.figure()

# fill figure with content here

display(HBox([slider, output]))
```

That way, the plot is correctly displayed once.